# Access a global string in a PHP class that is not defined as a global

Tags: php, class, global-variables

I have a unique situation that is hard to debug.

I need to set a global string inside a php class that is not strictly defined as a global,  the class must be in another file.

The `file.php` with the string has simply this:

```
//this cannot be changed
$foo_version = '1.1.1';
```

The `example.php` file trying to access this string must use a class:

```
class Bar extends Task {

      public function main() {

           require_once('../file.php');
           //global $foo_version; this doesn't work
           // update the database with this string, does not work

           update_option( 'db_field', $foo_version );

          }
      }
```

How can I get the `$foo_version` to return something inside the class?

Also nothing can be defined/done outside the class.

Comment: Pass it in an argument either through a construct or the main() function

Comment: doesn't `$GLOBALS['foo_version'] = '1.1.1';` work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a variable `$foo_version` and it can easily be changed.   You can use `define` to make it a constant instead [see PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

```
define("FOO_VERSION", "1.1.1");

class Bar extends Task {
    public function main() {
        require_once ('../file.php');
        update_option('db_field', FOO_VERSION);
    }
}
```

If you insist Replace `require_once` with `require` your code would work because PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

If you have used this in another class definitely it would not work. Change your code to the following

```
class Bar extends Task {
    public function main() {
        require ('../file.php');
        update_option('db_field', $foo_version);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$foo_version = '1.1.1';` cannot be altered or changed in any way.

Comment: You need to make it a constant not a variable if you don't want it changed  @Whyck

Comment: This is the challenge, I cannot alter it, I wish could.

Comment: Can you alter the `Bar` class

Comment: Yes the class can be altered, but it all code must be contained inside the class.

Comment: don't use `require_once` it would not include it if it detect you have used or included that fine before

Comment: For some reason the `require_once` was throwing it off, using `require` works fine, good hunch!

Comment: @Wyck the reason is in my answer .. you have balled the file before so it would not work ....

Answer (score 1):

If you include the file, and the variable is in the include file, you can just use it.

```
class Bar extends Task 
{
    public function main() {
       require_once('../file.php');
       update_option( 'db_field', $foo_version );
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured as much, unfortunately I cannot debug in the regular manner and it's not working.

Comment: If it is not working, then `$foo_version` is not a variable inside file.php. Show the code in file.php?

Comment: It's simply `<?php $foo_version = '1.1.1'; ?>`

Comment: just typed in the code and tested, works fine for me. How are you testing if it works?

Comment: This is being run by a command line script with lots of other functions and it's the last thing to run so I am not able to debug it the normal way, will have to troubleshoot further thanks.